# What are some of the user-created april fools gags that we've had in the past?

Tags: discussion

Sure, we have unicorns. We've also has some of our own april fools jokes on site. Sadly, they are often a pain to find, since they're deleted. What are some of these gags? Can we see what they are through the magic of screenshots?

(Created cause this often comes up - I wonder if an april-fools tag is in order)

Comment: StackExchange is globally known as the No Fun Zone so I think you'll have a hard time finding april fools gags.

Comment: There's at least two here. Problem is, being deleted they're not searchable. By creating a meta question, I can search for this, and problem solved!

Comment: well, after writing a query to fetch posts created on [the first of April](http://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/180196/fetch-all-questions-posted-on-the-first-of-april-sorted-by-decreasing-order-of-s), I realized that the Data Explorer doesn't return deleted posts..

Comment: Yup. I had trouble finding the gag below - I'll add this year's one later

Answer (score 9):

[This is a *fishy*](https://superuser.com/questions/407198/how-does-one-get-rid-of-fishy-behavior-in-windows/407201)(10K+ only, sorry! Screenshot below) question from 2013 about a vaio that suddenly had fish in it

This is a link to screenshot of the original thread
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyqW6.jpg. Answers range from the fish removal kit

[image]

To installing linux and using a turtle or a logo turtle to eat the fish.

Answer (score 4):

[2014's question](https://superuser.com/questions/736343/permanently-uninstalling-the-user) was about eliminating  or mitigating that most dangerous element of the computer system

x
͒ͤ̽͊̉T̨͙̗͈̭͚̩́͒̒ͅḧ̿͊ͫ̒͊ͭ͏̙͓̥̖̘̱ḙ̟̤̝̓̍̋̍ͮ̔ ̻͖̮̠̖ͮ̄͛̌̿ͧP̝̙͉̔̍͋͐͘r̓ͭo͕͕̠͕ͅb̙̙̮̲͕͉̫̄ͥͦ͟ļ̜̤̬̝̽̂̉ͯ̋̐͑e͉̙̪̗̯̱͛ͩ͂ͬ͊͡m̺̪̱̼̦ ̙͉̬͖͕̘̓ͥ̒̔ͯ̈T̨̰̱̝͈̝̺̙h͇ͮ̃́å͓̖͙͈̆̍̉̒̈̀t͓̬̜̏͑͋͋̔ͭ ̸͓͕͉ͥͧ̾͂E͉̯̝̳͈̎x͈̫͇̲͑̈̾͐̓̉͢i̗͙ͥͨ̐ͦ͗̑ͧs̹͈̩͇̠̤͔̑ͧ͛̓ͮ̚t̘͉͈̬̻̅͊̅ͮ̂ͅş̹̦̣ͤ͑̾ͩͬͧͬ ̹̅͛B̵̤̿̓ͥͅͅͅeͦ̊͒ͮ͐͝t̋͐̀ͮ̊͋̚҉̼̣̮w̗̳̼͔̱͎̾͜e̤̫̺̺͓͇ẻ̺͍̮͎̅n͉̣ͨ̾ ̻̣̐͞t̶̩̀̂ͬ̿̿̅h̥́ͣ͐͋͆e̤̥͚͚͝ ̲̜̼̜̮̟̳͂͘K͇̹̍̈́ẻ̗͉̩̄̋y͔̤͖̳͇̞̣͗̅ͤ̃͗͜b̢o̯̭̫̻͍̫̓́͐̌̚͠a͇̭͇͕ͧ̿͒ͪ͐̐r͓̬̠̳̫̹̱̔̇d̞͉̤̲͙ͮ̐ͧ ͕͉̹̜̙̿̀̑́ͬͯͣa̺͙nͨ͗͑͐́̊͏̟̝d̙͙͖̝͍̩ ̠̫̫͍̥͙̮̂̔ͮ̏̔C̡̝͚͖͍ͣh̼̱͔̟̺͎̹͌̇ͪ̐ã̷̪̓ͅi̥̣̮͓͍̣̰ͧͯ̌͋̀̈́̚r̫ͩ̉̑ͩ́̐͊͝ͅ ͎̭̝͔͉

Answers ranged from removing the user from the computer, removing the computer from the user, or simply removing the computers.

You can view a screenshot of the question and answers [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQ5qH.jpg) (yes, I'm aware imgur has converted it to jpeg and lowered the quality.There's a huge full quality download [here](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-n1o0rrMmd2k/Uz1QCO-IV4I/AAAAAAAAFQ0/pXUK4jwr4Hc/s0-I/userinstall.png) as an alternative)

Comment: And you didn't give my chair response an upvote? pft.

Comment: Full resolution screenshot is still pretty low resolution and therefore painful to read.

Comment: Imgur is messed it up. Try the "huge full quality download"

Comment: @Journeyman Geek: That version is still rather low resolution. Do you not have a full resolution copy? You know, one that has the same width as your screen? At full resolution, even a rather low quality JPEG would look okay--if that results in a smaller file. (I wouldn't be surprised if PNG was still smaller.)

Comment: PNGs smaller than JPGs? What strange and bizarre universe is this?

Comment: Niether of those screenshots are really readable. Want to try again?

Comment: Lemme try to find a place to stick a 731x11650 image ;p